# How can I take a screenshot (or video) of a rendered Xamarin Forms application?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, hockeyapp, visual-studio-mac, xamarin.insights

I need to quickly, and on demand, render a Xamarin forms content page, and take a screenshot of this.

The device I'm taking a screenshot of must be able to render custom dimensions, and ideally honor the device type (Android, iOS, Windows).

- What is the most efficient way to render this image, and then take a screenshot of this?

Note: I need to do this dynamically and in near real time. Consider this similar to https://appetize.io but for a completely different purpose

Comment: You may be able to get some of that functionality out of the Xamarin.Forms previewer. It's fairly new and has some limitations, but it comes installed out of the box these days and would be worth a look: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/